# Calculate the largest remainder of a number

Tags: java, performance, modulo

I am trying to calculate the largest remainder of a number, and find what number is dividing the original number to get the largest remainder. Here is my current code I am pretty sure it works. I just want to make it faster. Any Sugestions?

```
int c=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        if(c==2)
            pw.println(2);
        else if(c%2==0)
        {               
            pw.println(c-1);
        }
        else
        {
            max=0;
            int numDivided=0;
            for(int z=1; z<c; z+=2)
            {
                if(c%z>max)
                {
                    numDivided=z;
                    max=c%z;
                }
            }
            pw.println(numDivided);
```

new and faster code

```
c=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int largestRemainder = c % ((c/2) + 1);
pw.println(((c/2) + 1));
```

Comment: for all c > 0, `c%(c+1) == c` (and you can't get larger then it)

Comment: Either I don't understand the question, or the code in the question is incorrect. Consider the case of 8. The code returns 7, which only has remainder 1.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yeah the goal is to print out the largest number that produces the largest remainder, and that is what this does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest remainder is supposed to be less than the half of the input number. 
So you should use this formula, where `c` is the input integer:

```
int largestRemainder = c % ((c/2) + 1);
```

- For an even number, e.g. `c = 24` it gives `largestRemainder = 11`
- For an odd number, e.g. `c = 33` it gives `largestRemainder = 16`

And these results are actually correct.

Comment: For prime numbers however, the largest remainder is itself.

Comment: @fge i think you haven't understood the OP's question exactly. read again please.